# PHP: How do I add a parameter to an object reference?

Tags: php, oop

I have an object called $object formed as follows:

```
stdClass Object ( [PLAYER_ID] => 141 [STATUS_ID] => 16 [LOGIN_NAME] => mikemo21 [EMAIL] => mmogilefsky@yahoo.com [PT_BALANCE] => 13775 )
```

I'd like to add a parameter to this, perhaps so it appears as follows:

```
stdClass Object ( [PLAYER_ID] => 141 [STATUS_ID] => 16 [LOGIN_NAME] => mikemo21 [EMAIL] => mmogilefsky@yahoo.com [PT_BALANCE] => 13775 [NEW_FIELD] => VALUE)
```

What would be the proper syntax to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object properties in PHP do not need to be declared before they are assigned, so you can just assign a new property like you would an existing one:

```
$object->new_field = $value;
```

See this in action at http://www.ideone.com/a8Q3t.